# At the end of A Memory of Light, what is this character's expected lifespan?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

Related to but different from [A Memory of Light Question on the Epilogue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/a-memory-of-light-question-on-the-epilogue)

Spoiler warnings for the end of A Memory of Light, and therefore all of Wheel of Time!

After the Last Battle,

> Rand wakes up to find himself in Moridin's body. He still has his warder bonds to his three wives, but is unable to channel. Instead, "He... thought of the pipe being lit. And it was."

We know from [Average lifespan of non-channelers in Randland?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134502/average-lifespan-of-non-channelers-in-randland/134556#134556) that non-channelers tend to live for about 75-100 years, while channelers can live to be as much as 1,000 years old if not constrained by the Oath Rod.

Since the character in question can no longer channel, but has this other ability instead, has there been any word on how long he could live for? Could his new ability effectively make him immortal? Or is he now reduced to the usual lifespan of a non-channeler?

This question inspired while answering [Why did the vision disregard the intervention of the Dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134345/why-did-the-vision-disregard-the-intervention-of-the-dragon/134349#134349)

Comment: At this point in the story, that character is wholly unique and while they can't channel, they can apparently influence reality directly.  I think the lifespan of such a being is effectively "however long it wants", but there's absolutely know way to know from source material as there's nothing else like it in source material.

Comment: I was wondering if it ever came up in an interview or other info from Brandon Sanderson since the book's release, or if anyone can give a convincing reason for a specific answer

Comment: The ending is vague on purpose sanderson and the editors dont know what happens after

Comment: sanderson doesnt even know what rand is doing to like his pipe.

Comment: @Himarm ok, if the answer is "we don't know" you can make that an answer and I'll accept it. I didn't know if there was an answer, that's why I asked the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to go on of course, but since Rand basically is a surrogate for the Creator and lived many times before, I would say that his lifespan has been reduced to that of a normal man who can't channel. Immortality would mean he couldn't be reborn to battle Moridin.

Comment: That's a pretty compelling reason, well done! I'm gonna wait to confirm just to see if any more discussion gets sparked on here. Also a little nitpicky note, but I just noticed in my own question I stated he still has his warder bonds, so he will probably live as long as a warder does

Comment: Hmm..I hadn't thought of that...